# Finding all matches for a list of literally referenced pairs

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to check for the existence of several literally referenced values in the query that I am searching for in `tableName`. I have posted a generalized example of my attempt:

```
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    tableName
  WHERE column1 = 10
    AND CONCAT (column2, ",", column3) IN 
((column2_value_1, column3_value_1), 
(column2_value_2, column3_value_2));
```

`column2_value_1` and `column3_value_1` (and so on) would all be literally referenced by the values that would be found in those columns, e.g:

```
SELECT
    *
  FROM
    tableName
  WHERE column1 = 10
    AND CONCAT (column2, ",", column3) IN 
((123, "ABC"), 
(456, "DEF"));
```

How can I locate all instances in a table when I need to match two columns in the table with a list of pairs of literally referenced information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use CONCAT() for this case. MySQL supports tuple comparison:

```
WHERE column1 = 10
  AND (column2, column3) IN ((123, "ABC"), (456, "DEF"));
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#row-constructor-range-optimization